# Using tab key to select URL in address bar?

Tags: opera, opera-10

I use Firefox 3.x for much of my browsing and I constantly use the tab key (easy to hit) to select from my address history.  When I use Opera, tab takes me to the Search box, which of course makes perfect sense.  I could try to undo years of training and use down-arrow but first I thought that I see if Opera is secretly configurable.

Comment: You're looking for something like auto-complete for a URL?

Comment: I don't understand what you want :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Opera:

- choose `Tools` from the menu
- and then `Preferences`.
- Now goto `Shortcuts` and
- highlight your current keyboard setup in the lower box.
- Next, click on `Edit...`.
- Now unfold the `Advanced` item (last one in the list)
- and then the `Address dropdown Widget` item (again the last one).
- Now find the entry for "Next item"
- and double-click on the right part where it should currently say "Down".
- Replace "Down" with "Tab" and you're set.

Comment: Great.  Found the Shortcuts under Advanced...